# 404 error on published page with specific permalink

Tags: permalinks, 404-error, slug, single

I am experiencing a strange error with my Wordpress install.

I've got a dozen of pages, %postname% permalink structure, everything works fine.

For one of the published pages, I reverted it to draft mode, edited for a couple of days, then published it again. Now, when I try to access its permalink, I get a 404 error. If I change the slug by 1 symbol, it works. But the initial slug does not. Any idea how to fix it? Thanks!

Can share the website if necessary.

Edit: I did all the "fixes" that I found by Googling: refresh .htaccess, disable all plug-ins to see if it's a plugin issue, disable caching, update permalink structure... Nothing worked.

Comment: Not really an answer, but if you install the Query Monitor plugin it has a section for matched rewrite rules. It might help you debug the difference between a page that's working and one that's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I've spent a couple of more hours working on this and was examining my database through phpmyadmin. In the table wp_terms I noticed that I had terms identical to my page's slug. Turns out I had a tag named like this. I deleted the tag, and voila - no more 404 error. Hope this may help somebody.